# How can I download a file from base64 content in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser, base64

```
base64Content = "data:application/xml;base64," + xmlContent;
```

I have this line of code. The xmlContent (which is base64) is retrieved from the backend. I now want to download this base64 content as an XML file from the browser. How would I do this in JavaScript? Note that I do not want to do it by creating an  tag and setting the href to the base64 content and clicking the link programmatically.

Comment: "Note that I do not want to do it by creating an tag and setting the href to the base64 content and clicking the link programmatically." — Why not? That's the standard way.

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to do it using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), specifically its [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) method, creating firstly a BLOB from your base64 string

Comment: Would you happen to have an example of how this can be used?